# twitter oAuth cURL Example not working - why?

Tags: curl, twitter, oauth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [another twitter oAuth cURL access token request that fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295466/another-twitter-oauth-curl-access-token-request-that-fails)

The following code simply gives me:

**Failed to validate oauth signature and token**

```
        // Set url
        $url = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";

        // Params to pass to twitter and create signature
        $params['oauth_callback'] = "http://localhost/twitter/tweet/";
        $params['oauth_consumer_key'] = $this->consumerKey;
        $params['oauth_nonce'] = SHA1(time());
        $params['oauth_timestamp'] = time();
        $params['oauth_signature_method'] = $this->signatureMethod;
        $params['oauth_version'] = $this->version;
        ksort($params);

        // Signing
            // Concatenating
            $concatenatedParams = '';
            foreach($params as $k => $v)
            {
              $k = urlencode($k);
              $v = urlencode($v);
              $concatenatedParams .= "{$k}={$v}&";
            }
            $concatenatedParams = urlencode(substr($concatenatedParams,0,-1));

            $signatureBaseString = "POST&".urlencode($url)."&".$concatenatedParams;         
            $base64Hashmac = base64_encode( hash_hmac('sha1', $signatureBaseString, $this->secret."&", true) );
            $params['oauth_signature'] = urlencode($base64Hashmac);


        // Do cURL
        $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
            $exec = curl_exec ($ch);
            $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);

        print $exec;
```

Below is the info printed out from curls $info ...

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token
    [content_type] => text/html; charset=utf-8
    [http_code] => 401
    [header_size] => 919
    [request_size] => 181
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 1.176
    [namelookup_time] => 0
    [connect_time] => 0.127
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.127
    [size_upload] => 934
    [size_download] => 44
    [speed_download] => 37
    [speed_upload] => 794
    [download_content_length] => 44
    [upload_content_length] => 934
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.127
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [request_header] => POST /oauth/request_token HTTP/1.1
Host: api.twitter.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 934
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------7465678a46cc
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to specify exactly how it isn't working, things can "not work" in a large number of different ways.  Are you getting error results?  What are they, and from which calls?  Is any particular step failing?

To start with, you can't use "localhost" address as a callback URL, if the twitter server connects to "localhost" it would just be connecting to itself, not to you.

Also the way you're building `$concatenatedParams` leaves your `$signatureBaseString` only partly URL-encoded.  Instead of using `"{$k}%3D{$v}%26"` use `=` and `&` normally, and then `urlencode` the final completed `$concatenatedParams` when you add it to `$signatureBaseString`.

Comment: $concatenatedParams .= "{$k}%3D{$v}%26"; should complete the url encoding but I gave it a try and it still fails.

Comment: Ive updated the code as per your suggestion -> but not luck hey.

Comment: After being base64 encoded, the hash_hmac must also be url encoded before it is assigned to the `oauth_signature` parameter, I can't tell if that's happening inside `base64_encode`.

Comment: not its not but have updated to do so. no luck, same error.

Comment: You might want to try using GET and sending the oauth parameters as an Authorization: header, as recommended on Twitter's website:

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth#at-twitter

Comment: yeah I was trying that now now, not much documentation on it. And not a clue on how to do that. But it should accept POST params as well anyway.